# Laravel whereHas in many to many column id ambigious

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

There are my 3 tables:

```
- conversations:
  - id
  - name
- users:
  - id
  - name
- conversation_user:
  - id
  - conversation_id
  - user_id
```

Model conversation:

```
public function members() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'conversation_user');
}
```

Model user:

```
public function conversations() {
    return $this->hasMany(Conversation::class, 'conversation_user');
}
```

I want to retrieve if 2 users has already a conversation set.

My request

```
Conversation::withCount('members')->having('members_count', '==', 2)
->whereHas('members', function($query) use($user){
       $query->where('id', $user);
})->whereHas('members', function($query) use($auth){
       $query->where('id', $auth->id);
})->first();
```

1 conversation has at least 2 members, so it can have more; but here in my functionality I have input that search for users, and on click a user, I want to retrieve if the user logged in and the user selected has already a conversation.

But with my query I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `conversations`.*, (select count(*) from `users` inner join `conversation_user` on `users`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`user_id` where `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`conversation_id`) as `members_count` from `conversations` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `conversation_user` on `users`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`user_id` where `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`conversation_id` and `id` = 2) and exists (select * from `users` inner join `conversation_user` on `users`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`user_id` where `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`conversation_id` and `id` = 1) having `members_count` = == limit 1)

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the table names to avoid ambiguity:

```
Conversation::withCount('members')->having('members_count', '==', 2)
->whereHas('members', function($query) use($user){
       $query->where('users.id', $user);
})->whereHas('members', function($query) use($auth){
       $query->where('users.id', $auth->id);
})->first();
```